# how to use JSON API on C# Discord Bot

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm trying to make a discord bot which lookups user information based on given parameters on a command using JSON API.

lets say I want to lookup a user named **mellin111**

the api for that would be https://www.habbo.com/api/public/users?name=mellin111.
also im using SimpleJSON by bunny83 https://github.com/Bunny83/SimpleJSON

heres part of my code:

```
[Command("search", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]

        public async Task Search([Remainder] string echo)
        {
            string url = @"https://www.habbo.com/api/public/users?name=" + echo;
            // GET request
            WebClient ipcon = new WebClient();
            string response = ipcon.DownloadString(url);
            // Parse json
            dynamic json = JSON.Parse(response);

            var eb = new EmbedBuilder();
            eb
            .WithTitle("Search Result")
            .AddField("**Habbo IGN: **", "" + json["name"], false)
            .AddField("**Motto: **", "" + json["motto"], false)
            .AddField("**Member since: **", "" + json["memberSince"], false)
            .WithFooter("made with )
            //.WithThumbnailUrl("https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?size=m&figure=" + json["figureString"])
            .WithCurrentTimestamp()
            .WithColor(Color.Gold);
            await ReplyAsync(embed: eb.Build());
         }
```

although there are no errors on this code, it doesnt seem to return a response. is there any other way to get the data from the api?

Comment: You need to narrow down what exactly you are looking for assistance with. It doesn't return a response is very vague. Are you referring to the variable response that you expect to get back from `DownloadString`? Is the `Json.Parse` not returning a response? Is the command itself being called successfully but not returning a response?

Comment: @Anu6is i've improved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API seems to restrict requests from specific clients.
If you set a normalish user agent, it seems to work just fine.

An example straight from the WebClient Class' [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient):

```
var url = "https://www.habbo.com/api/public/users?name=mellin111";
var ipcon = new WebClient();
ipcon.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
var response = ipcon.DownloadString(url);
var json = JSON.Parse(response);
var yup_this_works = (DateTime)json["memberSince"];
//works assuming the "SimpleJSON" class is used like this, I havent personally used it
```

Comment: is there any other way to besides this code to achieve getting data from the api?

Comment: Well sure, without a doubt, but what's wrong with setting a user agent to your request?